# Add banner motd to postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I would like to present a banner motd (message of the day) to users that connect to a Postgresql database. Similar to cisco router and switch cli where you use:

```
banner motd "Seien Sie bitte vorsichtig....."
```

And then upon logging into the switch/router you see that message.

I'd like to see something similar when connecting to a database.

example:

```
$ psql postgres
psql (12.0)
Type "help" for help.
Seien Sie bitte vorsichtig.....

postgres=#
```

Comment: Maybe add a `\echo Please be careful` to [`psqlrc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10)? It will show before the `psql (12.0)` however

Comment: It looks like you’re logging in as a superuser. That’s a practice you should stop.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I log in as a normal user. the `postgres` user account does not seem to work for me

Comment: Your prompt ends with "#". On a default install this means that user is a superuser.

Comment: @Colin'tHart yes, but: `psql -U postgres postgres` -> `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. You can (and should) use `noinherit` to not have superuser (and other dangerous roles) when you connect and only activate them when required using `set role`. Also make sure autocommit is off so you can always use `rollback`. In this way you have removed 99.99% of the danger without requiring a MOTD.

Comment: Thanks Colin I am new to using SQL; I didn't know this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot force that on the server side, because the server cannot control what a client displays.

But yan can do it on the client side: create a `.psqlrc` file in your home directory that contains something like:

```
\echo Seien Sie bitte vorsichtig.....
```

But I assume, given the text of the warning, that you want this bannet only for certain sensitive databases.

For that, you could have  `banner` table in every database, and the statement in `.psqlrc` would be like:

```
\set QUIET on
\pset format unaligned
SELECT * FROM banner;
\pset format aligned
\set QUIET off
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to check the database first and print then? Like `IF (SELECT current_database()) = 'postgres' THEN (SELECT * FROM banner);`

Comment: Sure, you can run queries, assign the result to variables (`\gset`) and use `\if` to du different things based on the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help my friend